# Loss functions, decision theory for hyperparameters, or estimating the variance of an unknown prior

Tags: bayesian, variance, experiment-design, decision-theory

**How I got here**

I was originally interested in **point estimation** and the Bayes risk of some distribution $\pi$
$$
r(\pi) = \mathbb{E}_{\pi(x)}[ \mathbb{E}_{\Pr(y|e,x)}[L(x,\hat x(y|e))]], 
$$
where $L$ is some loss function and $\hat x$ is the posterior mean (here: Bayes estimator).  Here $e$ is some experimental design parameter.

If $L(x,\hat x) = |x-\hat x|^2$ (squared error), then the Bayes risk is also identical to the expected posterior variance.  So to optimally design experiments, I can use **negative expected variance** as a utility function to maximize.

Now suppose I iterate this procedure (sequential experimental design).  Although it is not necessarily the globally optimal solution, minimizing expected loss at each step is locally optimal (the greedy solution) and works quite well when compared to any non-optimized experiment designs.

**The problem**

In practice I need to apply these sequentially designed experiments to members of an **ensemble each with a different set of parameters $x$** whereas originally I assumed the parameters $x$ are chosen from the prior $\pi$ and fixed throughout.  Now, clearly point estimation is not the appropriate interpretation of this problem.  However, assuming the support of true distribution is contained in that of the prior I chose, my posterior should converge.

But it doesn't!  And the reason is because I am adaptively minimizing the expected variance of the posterior assuming the parameters are going to be the same at the experiment.

**The solution**

There are two types of solutions I can foresee being given (but I of course welcome a different type):

1. You are using the wrong loss function.  You need to introduce a hyperprior on some hyperparameters, define a loss on them and try to design experiments to minimize the Bayes risk.  And to this I ask: are there any treatments in the literature dealing with this decision theoretic framework for hyperparameters, or more specifically is there any natural loss functions on hyperparameters which reflect the error in estimating the variance of an unknown hyperprior?
2. Your decision theoretic framework is not really suited to your problem.  You should look at *these* papers or search Google for *this* jargon.

Comment: A solution of type 1; have a look at the literature on "loss estimation", in which one makes an additional decision that depends on how much (expected) loss there was for a primary decision - say a point estimate.

Comment: @guest - Thank you.  I found this:  http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176350960, which seems like it might be usefully.